# Is there way to reference overrideParameters from a file in ADF CI/CD?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I need to make use of `overrideParameters` in an ADF CI/CD scenario like described in the official Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#use-custom-parameters-with-the-resource-manager-template) - can't seem to find a way even in the [Azure Resource Group Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops) , is there a way to reference `overrideParameters` from a file instead of being forced to create a long ugly string with space seperation?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the values of each parameter from a variable template. That still requires you to list the override parameters but the values are sourced dynamically and thus can change across environments. Alternatively, you could put the whole deployment task into a template but then you would still have to think about dynamic environment variables in the template. A simple example below.

*variable-template.yml*

```
variables: 

  ...

  # subscription and resource group 
  azureSubscription: 'my_subscription'
  subscriptionId: 'my_subscription_id'
  resourceGroupName: 'my_rg'

  # key vault
  keyVaultName: 'my_kv'
  keyVaultSecretsList: 'storageAccountConnectionString,storageAccountKey'

  # data factory
  dataFactoryRepoPath: 'my_adf_repo_path'
  dataFactoryName: 'my_adf'

  # storage accounts
  storageAccountName: 'my_sa'

  ...
```

*azure-pipelines.yml*

```
...

- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ variables.azureSubscription }}
    KeyVaultName: ${{ variables.keyVaultName }}
    SecretsFilter: ${{ variables.keyVaultSecretsList }}
    RunAsPreJob: true

- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment'
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ variables.azureSubscription }}
    subscriptionId: ${{ variables.subscriptionId }}
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: ${{ variables.resourceGroupName }}
    location: 'West Europe'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf_branch/${{ variables.dataFactoryRepoPath }}/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf_branch/${{ variables.dataFactoryRepoPath }}/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
    overrideParameters: |
     -factoryName ${{ variables.dataFactoryName }} 
     -storageAccountSink_properties_typeProperties_url ${{ variables.storageAccountName }} 
     -storageAccountSink_accountKey $(storageAccountKey) 
     -storageAccountSink_connectionString $(storageAccountConnectionString)
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'

...
```